# Excel Macros Not Available When Workbook is Created Using Python

Tags: python, excel

Seems that when a workbook is created using python that the macros are not available. Even if I shut down, reboot, and reopen the files the created by python the macro options are still missing. However, if I manually create the excel file, then use python code to open the manually created excel file and run the macro it works fine.

Sample code provided, but seems that I may have an improper setting within excel or on the computer (government computer, though I have admin rights). I have enabled all macros in the macro settings, reviewed the available literature on this site, but am still having issues.

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True 
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
cell = ws.Cells(1)
cell.Value = 'text'
wb.Close(True, r'c:\AcousticAutomation\TestFolder\TestData\test.xls')
```

When I manually open ‘test.xls’, no macros are available in the macros section; therefore, I did not add the macro run line as the code will crash.

The same issue occurs if I convert/rename a txt file to cvs file, again when manually opening the csv in excel the data are there, but no macro options are avaialble:

```
os.rename('c:\..file path...\test.txt', 'c:\..file path..\test.csv')
```

However, if I manually create the file and use:

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
xl.Visible = True 
wb = xl.WorkBooks.open(r'c:\..test file path..\test.xls’) 
xl.Run(‘DeleteTopRows')
```

The macro is identified and works fine. So, I have tried multiple variations of creating workbooks, but it seems that whenever the file is created using python the macros “disappear” and the code crashes as the macro “does not exist” at that time.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Also, generally speaking, .txt and .csv do not properly support MS Excel macros. Of course, regardless of the filename, if the file contents are properly formatted, Excel will likely be able to read it / handle it. But no guarantees.

Comment: Using 2007. Even if I open a blank workbook using python, shut it down there, and open that workbook manually the macros are not there. Seems that whenever the workbook/file is created that the macros dissapear. I have not tried saving the manually created workbook after the macro runs in python. I am curious if macros in that saved file would also no longer be available.

Comment: If you create a blank workbook, why do you expect it to have macros?

Comment: So, just tried that. After python ran the excel macro on the manually created file and saved it, I opend the file. The macro options were still available. When I manually create the excel file, it opens as personal.xlsb I then resave it as "test.xlsm". When I use wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(), does it import the avaiable macros from personal.xlsb? If not, how do I do that?

Comment: Okay, so personal.xlsb is like a template file that Excel uses. When you create a new workbook in Excel, it loads personal.xlsb and uses that as the baseline for the new file you are creating (if you have macros in that file, they will come over). If you want to copy macros from personal.xslb to a new Excel file using Python, you will need to do so explicitly.

Comment: Ok, think I have it. I manually exported the macro in excel as .bas file. Then used the following command to import the macro into the newly opened workbook:    xl.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import('c:\..path..\DeleteTopRows.bas') Worked,  thanks selllikesybok

Answer (score 0):

I manually exported the macro in excel as .bas file. Then used the following command to import the macro into the newly opened workbook: xl.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import('c:..path..\DeleteTopRows.bas') Worked, thanks selllikesybok –  [Shea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1697835/shea)

Comment: Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.